# Jumping mechanics in Netwire

Tags: haskell, reactive-programming, frp, arrows, netwire

I think I need some incentive on how to make this, I'm not really experienced in general platforming game mechanics...

Anyway, my player figure has this up to now:

```
movePlayer = proc p -> do
    let gravity = 100
    sx <- keySpeed GLFW.LEFT GLFW.RIGHT 500 -< ()
    dy <- integralLim_ collision 0 -< (gravity, p)
    dx <- integralLim_ collision 0 -< (sx, p)
    returnA -< (sx, sy)
    where
        keySpeed k1 k2 s = onKey k1 (-s) <|> onKey k2 s <|> pure 0
        collision = undefined -- collision with the world
```

With `gravity`, the player object slowly falls down until there is something to stand on. Of course, the next step is to add jumping, in a `sin` curve... what is a simple way to add it using `netwire`? One that can also be have further collision detecting added to it?

I just have no idea where to begin with this one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all note that integrals work for tuples:

```
(x, y) <- integralLim_ f (x0, y0) -< ((dx, dy), w)
```

Now consider that gravity is an acceleration value.  You can easily add it to other acceleration values:

```
gravity = pure (0, -9.8)
jump    = pure (0, 1000) . holdFor 0.1 (keyPressed space) <|> pure (0, 0)

pos = integralLim_ collision p0 . integral_ v0 . (gravity ^+^ jump)
```

where `p0` is the initial position and `v0` the initial velocity.

Comment: Can't really get `pos` to work... what's that in proper arrow notation?

Comment: @LambdaDusk: Sorry, my failure.  I forgot the initial position/velocity.  Answer edited.

Comment: This works if I keep the space key pressed. If I just tap it, nothing happens, and keeping it pressed makes the sprite fly.